# Quando e por que mudou o til nos ditongos nasais da segunda letra para a primeira?

Tags: ortografia, mudanças-históricas

Hoje os ditongos nasais que aparecem no final de muitas palavras são escritos assim: *ão*, *ões*, etc.

Mas no passado, como é evidente na primeira edição d'*Os Lusíadas*, o til aparecia não sobre a primeira vogal no ditongo, mas na segunda.  Desta forma, o nome do autor foi impresso como *Luis **Camoẽs***, o que hoje seria *Luís **Camões***.

É possível, sem dúvida, essa mudança porque ambas vogais são nasais.<sup>1</sup>  Mas a minha pergunta é simples, quando mudou o til e há alguma motivo para aquela mudança?

---

<sup>1. Assim, talvez seria inclusive melhor escrito o ditongo com o til sobre ambas letras como *Camo︢e︣s*, mas por alguma razão —ou raza︢o︣ haha— isso nunca desenvolveu, embora nos manuscritos medievais era frequente encontrar tis sobre várias letras)</sup>

Comment: Na capa da [1ª edição](http://purl.pt/1/3/#/11) aparece realmente "Camoẽs"; possivelmente é gralha; porque pelo menos nas primeiras páginas da obra o til aparece na primeira letra do ditongo, incluindo em "Camões" noutros sítios (aparece mais uma vez "Camoẽs" no texto da licença, juntamente com vários "Camões). Contudo no sXVIII é comum encontrar-se o til da segunda letra; na segunda metade do sXIX já não. Para já não te sei dizer nada de mais concreto.